# Clojure.Spec derive or alias another spec

Tags: clojure, data-generation, clojure.spec, specification-pattern

I'd like to use clojure spec to build up a set of type constraints that can be aliased or further constrained by other specs.

For example, I might have many fields that all need to be valid sanitized markdown.

The following example works for validation (`s/valid?`) but not for generation (`gen/generate`)

```clj
(s/def ::sanitized-markdown string?)
(s/def ::instruction-list #(s/valid? ::sanitized-markdown %)) ;; works

(gen/generate (s/gen ::instruction-list)) ;; fails
```

However `(gen/generate (s/gen ::sanitized-markdown))` does work.

Is there a way to extend `::instruction-list` from `::sanitized-markdown` so that it preserves all behavior?

Comment: `(s/def ::instruction-list ::sanitized-markdown)`?

Comment: *facepalm* I thought I had tried that. I must have run into a different error and conflated the two issues.
I'll happily mark that as an answer if you want to claim it

Comment: @Lee, Would you like to claim the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias another spec by providing it directly to `s/def`:

```
(s/def ::instruction-list ::sanitized-markdown)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `s/merge` when merging map specs and `s/and` in other cases.

```
(s/def ::sanitized-markdown string?)
(s/def ::instruction-list (s/and ::sanitized-markdown #(> (count %) 10)))

(s/valid? ::instruction-list "abcd")
;; false
(s/valid? ::instruction-list "abcdefghijkl")
;; true

(gen/generate (s/gen ::instruction-list)) 
;; "178wzJW3W3zx2G0GJ1931eEeO"
```

An example with maps

```
(s/def ::a string?)
(s/def ::b string?)
(s/def ::c string?)
(s/def ::d string?)
(s/def ::first-map (s/keys :opt [::a ::b]))
(s/def ::second-map (s/keys :opt [::c ::d]))
(s/def ::third-map (s/merge ::first-map ::second-map))

(s/valid? ::third-map {:a "1" :d "2"})
;; true
(gen/generate (s/gen ::third-map))
;; {::b "gvQ7DI1kQ9DxG7C4poeWhk553", ::d "9KIp77974TEqs9HCq", ::c "qeSZA8NcYr7UVpJDsA17K"}
```